# Using the same function with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have multiple buttons that should call the OpenPanel function but apparently chrome doesn't like it when I use inline event handlers. Are there any alternatives? Thanks!

Html:

```
<button id="showBg" class="panelB" onclick="OpenPanel(this)">Btn1</button>

<button id="showNews" class="panelB" onclick="OpenPanel(this)">Btn2</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function OpenPanel(elem){
 alert (elem.id);
}
```

Chrome Error:

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Comment: did you try adding `;` after OpenPanel(this)?

Comment: @user5014677 Yea, just did. Chrome still doesn't like it. Here is the error: `Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wf4s889w/

Comment: I don't find any issue in either chrome or firefox!

Comment: You're writing an extension?

Comment: @Barmar Yea, I am writing an extension, sorry for not clarifying. I tried to add it to tags and I had to have a certain about of rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery you could use the class as a selector and a click function...

HTML:

```
<button id="showBg" class="panelB">Btn1</button>
<button id="showNews" class="panelB">Btn2</button>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('button.panelB').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

If for some reason you need to call your `OpenPanel` function, that is expecting a DOM element instead of a jQuery object...

```
function OpenPanel(elem) {
    alert(elem.id);
}

$('button.panelB').click(function() {
    OpenPanel(this);
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Good to hear! Have a nice day and happy coding.

Comment: What on earth is this for? `$(this).get(0)` You create a jQuery object with one element in it, and then you get the first element back out of it.  That's exactly the same as just using `this` **by itself** in the first place!

Comment: @Quentin My fault... I wasn't sure if the `this` javascript dom element was assigned to the button dom element inside of the jquery event. Now I know it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> chrome doesn't like it when I use inline event handlers

Chrome has no problem with inline event handlers. The error message says that the problem is your Content Security Policy.

Either through HTTP headers or meta tags you have banned yourself from using inline event handlers.

This is probably for the best. Inline event handlers come with annoying gotchas.

Bind your event handlers with JavaScript instead.

```
function openPanelHanler(event) {
    OpenPanel(this);
}

var panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panelB");
for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
    panels[i].addEventListener("click", openPanelHander);
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. I am actually writing an extension, so maybe that's why?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use:

```
$(".panelB").click(function(){
   {...}
});
```

`$(this)` contains the current element that's been clicked.